# Stochastic integration by parts problem

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus

I have a question regarding stochastic integration by parts. I am supposed to show that
\begin{align*}
    \int^t_{t-h} \sigma_s^2 \, ds &= \int_{t-h}^t (t-h-s) \, d\sigma^2_s,
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_t^2$ is an Itô process. By using the integration by parts formula I get
\begin{align*}
    \int^t_{t-h} \sigma^2_s \, ds &= t \sigma_t^2 - (t-h)\sigma_{t-h}^2 - \int^t_{t-h} s \, d\sigma^2_s. 
\end{align*}
If
\begin{align*}
    \int_{t-h}^t (t-h) \, d \sigma^2_s = t \sigma^2_t - (t-h)\sigma_{t-h}^2,
\end{align*}
then the desired equality holds, but I do not understand why this equality holds. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: This does not seem true, what if $t=h$ and $\sigma_{s}^{2} = s$?

Comment: @Manifoldski For $t=h$ both sides are zero so it happens to be true. It seems however wrong for other reasons. See my answer.

Comment: @KurtG. For $t=h$ both sides are zero? I get $$\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{s}^{2} \ ds = \int_{0}^{t} -s \ d\sigma_{s}^{2}$$ for the first equality and $$0 = t\sigma_{t}^{2}$$ for the last.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $S_t=S_0+\int_0^ta_s\,ds+\int_0^tb_s\,dW_s$ is an Ito process, then it follows from Ito's formula applied to $f(t,x)=tx$ that
$$\tag{1}
d(tS_t)=t\,dS_t+S_t\,dt.
$$
This special case is also known as integration-by-parts. In integral form this is
$$\tag{2}
tS_t=\int_0^ts\,dS_s+\int_0^tS_s\,ds.
$$
Therefore,
$$\tag{3}
tS_t-(t-h)S_{t-h}=\int_{t-h}^ts\,dS_s+\int_{t-h}^tS_s\,ds\,.
$$
We can write the left hand side in a form that is more complicated:
$$\tag{4}
\int_{t-h}^tt\,dS_s+\int_0^{t-h}h\,dS_s+hS_0
$$
so that (3) becomes equivalent to
$$\tag{5}
\int_{t-h}^tS_s\,ds=\int_{t-h}^t(t-s)\,dS_s+\int_\color{red}{0}^\color{red}{t-h}h\,dS_s+hS_0\,.
$$

- The formula you are supposed to show looks wrong indeed because the integral with integrand $h$ has the wrong sign and the wrong integration limits.

The simplest version of this equation is in my opinion
$$\tag{6}
\int_{t-h}^tS_s\,ds=\int_{t-h}^t(t-s)\,dS_s+hS_{t-h}\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Realising that  $ tS_t - (t-h)S_{t-h} = \int^t_{t-h} t \, dS_s + \int^{t-h}_{0} h \, dS_s $, was quite helpful, as my answer is now at least on the form of the solution. I agree that what I try to prove is wrong (I think I instead am to show that $\int_{t-h}^t \sigma^2_s \, ds - \sigma_t^2$ takes this form). I am wondering about one detail in the equality above. Don't we have that
$\int^t_{t-h} t \, dS_s + \int^{t-h}_{0} h \, dS_s = tS_t - (t-h)S_{t-h} - hS_0$.
What happens to the $hS_0$ term?

Comment: I have numbered all equations to make the discussion easier. Which step (n) to (n+1) you are having trouble with ? Actually I think there is indeed a term $S_0$ missing. Will edit the answer once more.

Comment: I now fully understand all steps. I was confused by the missing term. I agree that the formula I want to show must be incorrect. I guess I will have to ask the professor if there's a typo in the exercise. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let me abbreviate $\sigma^2_s$ to $X_s$. Then (assuming $h>0$)
$$
\eqalign{
\int_{t-h}^t(t-h-s)dX_s 
&= (t-h)(X_t-X_{t-h}) -\int_{t-h}^t s\,dX_s\cr
&= (t-h)(X_t-X_{t-h}) +\int_{t-h}^t X_s\,ds-sX_s\Big|_{t-h}^t.\cr
&= (t-h)(X_t-X_{t-h}) +\int_{t-h}^t X_s\,ds-tX_t+(t-h)X_{t-h}.\cr
&= -hX_t +\int_{t-h}^t X_s\,ds.\cr
}
$$
Your formula is not quite right, in general.

Comment: Since $-\int_{t-h}^th\,dX_s=-hX_t+hX_{t-h}$ that's exactly (6) from the already existing answer where it is also mentioned that the formula OP was supposed to show is wrong.